# Gratis (or much cheaper) alternative to Add-in Express [develop MS Office add-ins in Delphi]

Tags: software-development, delphi, microsoft-office

[Add-in Express](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-delphi/index.php) allows Delphi developers to create add-ins for Microsoft Office products (I am particularly interested in Outlook).

While this is an excellent product, I find the [$349 price](https://www.add-in-express.com/purchase/index.php?family=vcl#qty3|1) just a tad too expensive.

I am looking for and alternative for [Delphi](https://www.embarcadero.com/de/products/rad-studio) or [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus-ide.org/).

Preferably gratis, I could maybe go as high as $100, but would prefer not to.

I am thinking of:

- adding buttons to the ribbon bar
- generating dialogs / user input forms
- accessing Outlook data, such as address book & calendar
- accessing the Windows file system, for attachments
- possibly generating & displaying reports directly in Office apps, like Outlook, with user interaction to tweak the reports

I am aware that I can generate VSTO and web-helper code from MS Visual Studio, but my C# is rusty. I suppose that I could fall back on Visual Basic (once learned, never forgotten :-)

But, I don't see the ease of development in VS that is available in Add-in Express.

If there is no answer for Delphi or Lazarus, I would be open to alternatives offering similar functionality.

[image]